# Page Specific JavaScript with Middleman

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, middleman

I am using Middleman for a project and would like to only load certain JS files on certain pages. How can I configure the asset pipeline to only load specific JS files? I've found answers for the asset pipeline in rails applications (ex. http://blog.seancarpenter.net/2012/11/05/page-specific-javascript-with-the-asset-pipeline/) but I'm not sure how to apply this Middleman.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
//= require_tree ./general
//= require_tree ./ckeditor
//= require_tree ./custom
```

In application.js file include the path of those js files which you want to load by default for all the applications. In the above code ./general will include all the js files under app/assets/javascripts/general/ and so on.

If you want certain js file to be loaded in your pre-defined view page then you need to call it explicitly from that view page as:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'your_custom_js_file_name' %>
<% end %>
```

The file location of `your_custom_js_file_name.js` file is `app/assets/javascript`

We need to yield script in the layout file so, include this:

```
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Besides you need to specify to compile in for production environment. So in production.rb do this:

```
 config.assets.precompile += [ "your_custom_js_file_name.js", "your_custom_js_file_name2.js"]
```

Credit goes to: [site](https://rubyonrails4u.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/ruby-on-rails-page-specific-javascript/)

Comment: I had to use  `<%= yield_content :scripts %>`. source: https://middlemanapp.com/basics/helper-methods/#output-helpers